# setting textbox's value of MSI

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I need to set the value of a textbox in Windows MSI

the command i am using is

```
MSIEXEC.EXE /I Search.msi  EDITA1="http://abc/Server" TARGETVDIR=ChemLab/SearchClient" /QN /Lv* c:\temp\Search_UnInstall_Install.log ALLUSERS=1
```

Even after setting the value for textbox `(EDITA1="http://abc/Server")` from command line, the MSI shows the default value

what is that i am missing out?
Please help,thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a Visual Studio setup project, and if so, the MSI contains internal custom actions to reset them. If you look at the CustomAction table you may see some, and where they are called, use the Orca tool.

The other issue can be that those properties aren't in the SecureCustomProperties list in the Property table of the MSI file, and that means they can lose their values between the UI start and the execute sequence.